# Using the HTML Select tag to switch between languages in a multilingual website

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Before
I have a website that i built to switch from English to Dutch just by clicking on a hyperlink i.e `<a>`
I had 2 files; `de.php` and `en.php` with following structures;

de.php

```php
<?php
  $lang = array(
    "title" => "hengst Bank, bankieren kredietkaarten, Leningen en Merill Investeren www.stallionbank.com",
    "titleUserAccount"=>"Gebruikers account|Stallion Bank",
    "Home" => "Huis",
    "lang_en"=>"Engels",
    "lang_de"=>"Dutch"
    );
?>
```

en.php

```php
<?php
  $lang = array(
    "title" => "Stallion Bank&mdash; Banking, credit cards,Loans and Merill Investing www.stallionbank.com",
    "titleUserAccount"=>"User Account|Stallion Bank",
    "lang_en"=>"English",
    "lang_de"=>"Dutch"
    );
?>
```

To load a specific language. User only has to click on the hyperlink

```html
<a href="index.php?lang=en"><?php echo $lang['lang_en']?></a>
<a href="index.php?lang=de"><?php echo $lang['lang_de']?></a>
```

index.php

```html
<head>
  <title><?php echo $lang['title']?></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  .....
```

**Now**, there's need for me to add other languages such as french, portugese and spanish. so I prepared
`fr.php`, `pt.php` and `sp.php`
`
fr.php

```php
<?php

$lang = array(
  "title" => "Stallion Bank&mdash; bancaire, cartes de crédit,Prêts et Merill Investing www.stallionbank.com",
  "titleUserAccount"=>"Compte d'utilisateur|Stallion Bank",
  "lang_en"=>"Anglaise",
  "lang_fr"=>"French"
  );
```

etc for `pt.php` and `sp.php`

having users using links to load lnaguage of their choice isnt so professional and may be cluster the website.
So resorted to using select tag.

index.php

```
<div align = "left">
  <select  name="lang" id="lang" onChange="window.location='index.php?lang='+this.value">
    <option value="en" <?php if( $lang =='en'){echo "selected";}?>>English</option>
    <option value="fr" <?php if( $lang =='fr'){echo "selected";}?>>French</option>
    <option value="de" <?php if( $lang =='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Dutch</option>
    <option value="sp" <?php if( $lang =='sp'){echo "selected";}?>>Spanish</option>
    <option value="pt" <?php if( $lang =='pt'){echo "selected";}?>>Portugese</option>
  </select>
```

How do I go about this so that if a user selects a particular langauge from the drop down menu, the index.php page will load the corresponding `sp.php` or `pt.php` or `en.php` or `fr.php` accordingly?

Do I need AJAX for this as the page will have to reload without user having to submit or button?Obviously, there is submit button.

You can visit `www.betensured.com` to see the behaviour am looking for.
Observe how the page changes upon selecting a different language from the drop-down menu.

Comment: maybe you also need to add `<html lang="en">` or `<html lang="fr">` ...

Comment: I don’t get what your actual question is here. You already _had_ the server-side logic to show the right content, when `index.php?lang=xy` gets requested, right? Now all that has changed is that you are not navigating to these URLs by clicking on links any more, but that you navigate there via JavaScript, once the user makes a different choice in the select field. The URL format is still exactly the same, so why should this need any more modification on the server side now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done in a project

```html
<li class="lang">
  <select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" 
          class="lang-selector">
    <option value="../en" class="lang-option">
      <a hreflang="EN" rel="alternate">En</a>
    </option>
    <option value="../fr/" class="lang-option" selected>
      <a hreflang="FR" rel="alternate">Fr</a>
    </option>
  </select>
</li>
```

At the root of the project I had my languages sections (/fr/ , /en/, /esp/ ...) each directory contain an index.php file, so when I select my language option the selected_language/index.php is loaded

Comment: if you want to see what this does https://bugsminers.com

Comment: In essence, are you trying to say that your language translations was taken care of just by adding the corresponding lang attribute values in each fr/index.php, en/index.php, esp/index.php file?

Comment: Yeah basically I did this the most simple way I was able to think when I was doing this

Comment: Thanks @Axel Moriceau.Your suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps ...

```js
(function()  // IIFE
  {
  const defaultLang  = 'en'
    ,   langSelector = document.getElementById('lang-select')
    ,   htmlTag    = document.querySelector('html')
    ,   langElms   = [...document.querySelectorAll('*[lang]')]
    ,   docTitle   = 
          { en: 'English document title'
          , fr: 'Titre Français pour le document '
          }
  // remove <html lang="en"> from langElms
  let i_html = langElms.findIndex(el=>el===htmlTag)
  if (i_html>-1)  langElms.splice(i_html,1)  

  // set initial language according to browser language, or default Lang if this none of site languages
  let initLang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || defaultLang).substring(0,2)
  if (!docTitle[initLang])  initLang = defaultLang

  langSelector.value = initLang
  showLang()

  function showLang()
    {
    let lang = langSelector.value
    htmlTag.lang   = lang
    document.title = docTitle[lang]

    langElms.forEach(el=>
      {
      if (el.lang===lang) el.classList.remove('noDisplay')
      else                el.classList.add('noDisplay')
      })
    }

  // the final touch !
  langSelector.onchange = showLang
  })()
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none !important;
  }
  
  /* cosmetic part */
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  }
```

```html
<select id="lang-select">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">Français</option>
  </select>

  <p lang="fr">ce paragraphe est en Français</p>
  <p lang="en">this paragraph is in English</p>

  <div lang="fr">ce block est en Français</div>
  <div lang="en">this block is in English</div>
```